# Spring Bind @RequestBody to other data types

Tags: java, spring

It is very common to see a JSON RequestBody being bind to POJO, like following:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users", headers="Accept=application/json",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody CustomerInfo customerInfo){
...
}
```

Is it possible to have @RequestBody bind to non-POJO but other data types like primitive and non primitive data types?

E.G:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/users", headers="Accept=application/json",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody Set<Integer> ids){
...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Per your example,

```
public void create(@RequestBody Set<Integer> ids){
    ...
}
```

It will receive something like `[1,2,3]` as the request body perfectly fine.

For another example for primitive,

```
public void create(@RequestBody int id) {
    ...
}
```

It will receive something like `1` as the request body perfectly fine.

However, for the latter example, I would not say it is `application/json`.

Comment: What if it's `Set<MyPojoClass>`, would it still work?

Answer (score 1):

Per docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody

You can use a Java Object to try as the type parameter of a `@RequestBody`. That said I don't think there is a support for primitives.

Per docs you have this options:

> The RequestMappingHandlerAdapter supports the @RequestBody annotation
>   with the following default HttpMessageConverters:
>
> - ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter converts byte arrays.
> - **StringHttpMessageConverter converts strings.**
> - **FormHttpMessageConverter
>     converts form data to/from a MultiValueMap.**
> - SourceHttpMessageConverter converts to/from a
>     javax.xml.transform.Source.